# Python - OPENPYXL форматированное время с 1970 г

Tags: python, openpyxl

Как получить правильную дату 19.05.2017 используя cell.internal_value?

Проблема в том, что извлекается число, равное количеству времени, начиная с эпохи от 1 января 1970г. Как получить секунды, используя эту функцию, чтобы при конвертации из секунд получить точную дату 19.05.2017?

Comment: чему `cell.number_format` равен? И другие атрибуты: `{name: attr for name in dir(cell) if not name.startswith('__')
        for attr in [getattr(cell, name)] if not callable(attr)}`

Comment: cell.number_format - QDateTime

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss

Answer (score 0):

Может быть достаточным сменить формат даты, используя именованные стили:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime as DT
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active
dt = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = DT.date.today()

cell = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2)
cell.value = dt  # same value
my_date_style = NamedStyle(name='my_date_style', number_format='dd.mm.yyyy')
cell.style = my_date_style  # different style
workbook.save('book.xlsx')
```

Если открыть `book.xlsx`, то первая ячейка будет показана как: `2018-05-27`, а вторая `27.05.2018`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Попробую